# STM32 Nucleo F411RE ST-LINK error (DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR)

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f4, nucleo, st-link

I do not have any experience with programming STM32 boards. In windows device manager, it says that my ST-LINK driver is up to date (latest version).
The board LEDs light up and everything seems to be normal until I try to connect to the board through ST-LINK.
I am getting the following error in STM32CubeProgrammer when trying to connect to the Nucleo F411RE board.

```
  23:49:44:122 : Disconnected
  23:49:48:131 : STLinkUSBDriver.dll loaded
  23:49:48:133 : STLinkUSBDriver.dll loaded
  23:49:48:133 : ST-LINK SN  : 066CFF545150898367065053
  23:49:48:133 : ST-LINK FW  : V2J39M27
  23:49:48:134 : Board       : NUCLEO-F411RE
  23:49:48:134 : Voltage     : 4.89V
  23:49:48:137 : Error: ST-LINK error (DEV_TARGET_CMD_ERR)
  23:49:48:147 : Disconnected
```

I am using a regular cable.

In the NOD_F411RE storage F:/ I can find two files:
FAIL.TXT containing

```
The interface firmware FAILED to reset/halt the target MCU
```

And DETAILS.TXT containing

```
Version: V2J39M27
Build:   Oct 22 2021 16:50:45
```

Any ideas what I can try next? I am pretty lost.

Comment: you can simply drag and drop your .bin file over, you dont need to use stlink.

Comment: I normally update the firmware on the board when I get a new one.  its a java tool , works on whatever operating system.

Comment: why is the voltage so high? The STM32F411 is a 3V3 MCU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I had my Nucleo mounted on a breadboard. Some of the pins were in shortcircuit. That's it. Disconnected it from the breadboard and it worked just fine :D.
I thought that the pins would not be active without me assigning them for a certain connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Nucleo F411RE is already equipped with a JTAG interface. If you want to use your stlink, you probably have to disconnect the upper part of the board (which is the JTAG interface).

Comment: that debug interface supports stlink, and I suspect that is what they are trying to use.

Comment: You are probably right @old_timer, but I was confused by the statement "I try to connect to the board through ST-LINK".

Comment: I assume folks think they need to but for a number of these boards you just drag and drop and maybe use stlink for debugger stuff, can use it for loading as well, but ...

Comment: @Sergiu Fratila has to clarify its question.

Comment: yes a clarification is required.  more information needed on the problem.